# MVC C# application, percent textbox vs. percent database save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering what the simplest way to implement the following -

I have a textbox, that a user can enter in a percentage, the number must be stored as divided by 100.

Example:
If the user enters into the textbox 45.2 this is to be stored in the database as .452.

What is the simplest way to implement this in an MVC C# application?

I have a `PercentDisplay` property and a `Percent` property on the model. When the model comes back to the controller, I divide `PercentDisplay` by 100 and put the result into `Percent`, but I would like to do this without the extra property.

Any suggestions? Is there someway to just handle this in the View?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to store the percentage in your database like that.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I typically use a ViewModel for. Your model has 0.452, your ViewModel has 45.2 and converts between the two, the View binds to the ViewModel.

Comment: @tnw: There's plenty of legitimate reasons to store it that way. If it's being accessed elsewhere and being used for multiplication, for example, a decimal may be the best representation for that purpose. When displaying to the user, the % form makes more sense. I don't think "why" is particularly useful here.

Comment: @ColinDeClue That's why it's a comment, and since the user's question is only about not having an extra property that's directly a result of having to do this conversion, I felt it was perfectly valid input. And in response to your example, he could just as easily convert the value after he pulls it from the database instead.

Comment: @tnw At a guess, I'd say that storing a percentage like that enables you to multiply things by it with no further processing: `result = input * percentage` is a touch easier to understand than `result = input * (percentage/100)`. You have to multiply when displaying it, but that's more "normal" and less likely to confuse; conversions for display are pretty standard.

Comment: @anaximander You're splitting hairs at best. You'd have to be brand new to arithmetic/programming to find one of those "easier to understand" than the other. There's no way the latter even causes any notable "further processing", so I don't really see your point.

Comment: @tnw I did say "a *touch* easier". The point isn't that one method requires more processing; it's just that one method puts the processing somewhere where it's marginally easier to work out what it's doing. I agree, there's barely any difference, but if you have to pick one or the other, then it's generally best to store it in the format that can be used for your internal arithmetic/logic without conversion, and then convert it for display - it's more in keeping with the standard three-layer architecture. But you're right; it makes very little difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 layers here and 2 boundaries.

1. View-Controller
2. Controller-Model

You should be receiving the value as 45.2 from the user in the View. This would then arrive in the Controller as 45.2.

In the Controller, you should either convert it to 0.452 (using a helper Business Logic class) or send 45.2 to the DB via the Model to be stored as 0.452.

You should NOT be handling the conversion in the view. Imagine if you had more than 1 views. You would be doing the conversion multiple times. That defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks Umar, I took your advise.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `get` operation of the `Percent` property to do the cast and division and not have a `set` operation. I can't provide you an example really because you didn't provide the code that does the casting and division.

On the other hand, here's an example:

```
public decimal Percent
{
    get
    {
        var p = decimal.Parse(PercentDisplay);
        return p / 100;
    }
}
```

you would want to wrap the parse, and maybe even use `TryParse` instead, to ensure safety.

Comment: This still has two properties, so it may not be simpler than what he already has. However, it does sound like he's doing the division in the controller, so this would definitely be better in that case.

Comment: This is good only if there isn't a set - imagine if `a = a` changed the value of `a`.

Comment: @Jeff, and note there isn't a `set` - for the very reason that the `Percent` is built on the foundation of the `PercentDisplay`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your statement.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - I was just pointing out that it's ONLY good if there isn't a `set`, adding emphasis to a point you made (but only briefly) in your answer.  I could see someone using your answer, but needing to set the value, and thinking, "adding a `set` should be ok..." and that's how bad code happens to good people.